# loop in terraform to assign input values from complex object

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, hcl

I'm having some trouble assigning input values from a loop in terraform. I have a variable that has a url and list of nsrecords I want to use this variable to build out dynamic NS records on a hosted zone.

This doesn't work but I think it shows what I'm attempting to do:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "erp_subdomain_dev_portalns_record" {
  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  ttl = 300
  type = "NS"
  {for subdomain in var.subdomain_list : [  
    name = subdomain.url
    records = [for nsrecord in subdomain.nsrecords]
}
```

vars.tf

```
variable "subdomain_list" {
  type = list(object({
    url = string
    nsrecords = list(string)
  }))
  description = "List all sub domains for erp.tylerapi.com"
  default = [{
    url = "test1.com",
    nsrecords = ["ns-333.awsdns-26.com",
    "ns-4444.awsdns-06.org",
    "ns-5555.awsdns-26.co.uk",
    "ns-6666.awsdns-62.net"]
  },
  {
    url = "test2.com",
    nsrecords = ["ns-5678.awsdns-21.org",
    "ns-1234.awsdns-26.co.uk",
    "ns-123.awsdns-31.net",
    "ns-345.awsdns-42.com"]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work but I had to adjust the variable and not use a list(object)

var.tf

```
variable "subdomain_list" {
  description = "List all sub domains for erp.tylerapi.com"
  default = {
    "test1.com" = [
      {
        nsrecords = ["ns-888.awsdns-26.com",
    "ns-5678.awsdns-06.org",
    "ns-4321.awsdns-26.co.uk",
    "ns-1234.awsdns-62.net"]
      }
    ],
    "test2.com" = [{
      nsrecords = ["ns-1011.awsdns-21.org",
    "ns-789.awsdns-26.co.uk",
    "ns-456.awsdns-31.net",
    "ns-123.awsdns-42.com"]
   } ]
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
locals {
  subdomains = flatten([
    for key in keys(var.subdomain_list) : [
        for nsrecord in var.subdomain_list[key] : {
          url = key
          nsrecordslist = nsrecord
        }
      ]
  ] )
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "erp_subdomain_dev_portalns_record" {
  count = length(local.subdomains)
  allow_overwrite = true
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  ttl = 300
  type = "NS"
  name = local.subdomains[count.index].url
  records = local.subdomains[count.index].nsrecordslist["nsrecords"]
}
```